# ERROR: Error reading "src/core/database/config.ts"

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, pg

I want to migrate db in Node Nest.JS application.
`npx sequelize-cli db:migrate` shell command
throws an the below exception:

### Exception detail:

Error: TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /Users/../src/core/database/config.ts

### config.ts File

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    default: {
      username: process.env.DB_USER,
      password: process.env.DB_PASS,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME_GLOBAL,
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      port: process.env.DB_PORT,
      dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT,
    },
    transaction: {
      username: process.env.DB_USER,
      password: process.env.DB_PASS,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME_TRANSACTION,
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      port: process.env.DB_PORT,
      dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT,
    },
  },
  test: {
    default: {
      ...
    },
    transaction: {
      ...
    },
  },
  staging: {
    default: {
     ...
    },
    transaction: {
      ...
    },
  },
  production: {
    default: {
      ...
    },
    transaction: {
      ...
    },
  },
};
```

### .sequelizerc file

```
const path = require('path');

require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
  'seeders-path': path.resolve('src/core/database', 'seeders'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('src/core/database', 'migrations'),
  config: path.resolve('src/core/database', 'config.ts'),
};
```

### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
  }
}
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "des",
  "author": "auth",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://....git"
  },
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "NODE_ENV=development nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "cp -rv dist/i18n dist/src/ && nest start",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "NODE_ENV=test jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
    "db:seed": "npx sequelize-cli db:seed:all",
    "db:migrate": "npx sequelize-cli db:migrate",
    "testdb:seed": "NODE_ENV=test npx sequelize-cli db:seed:all",
    "testdb:migrate": "NODE_ENV=test npx sequelize-cli db:migrate",
    "copy-assets": "cp -rv dist/i18n dist/src/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@elastic/ecs-winston-format": "^1.3.1",
    "@nestjs-modules/mailer": "^1.6.0",
    "@nestjs/axios": "^0.0.5",
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^1.1.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^8.0.1",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/sequelize": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/serve-static": "^2.2.2",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^5.1.4",
    "@nestjs/throttler": "^2.0.0",
    "@sentry/node": "^5.9.0",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^5.2.3",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1048.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "class-transformer": "0.4.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "elasticsearch": "^16.7.2",
    "faker": "^5.5.3",
    "firebase": "^9.5.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.0",
    "generate-password": "^1.7.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "helmet": "^4.6.0",
    "json2csv": "^5.0.6",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "jwk-to-pem": "^2.0.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.4",
    "nest-winston": "^1.6.2",
    "nestjs-i18n": "^8.2.1",
    "nestjs-redis": "^1.3.3",
    "nestjs-throttler-storage-redis": "^0.1.18",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.2",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-firebase-jwt": "^1.2.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "pg": "^8.7.1",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "redis": "^4.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.11.0",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.3.0",
    "sequelize-typescript": "^2.1.1",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.6",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.12",
    "winston": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.178",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.4",
    "@types/sequelize": "^4.28.10",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.2.5",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.10.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share package.json and tsconfig file?

Comment: I added these two files that you want.

Comment: Try again after setting ```esModuleInterop: true``` in tsconfig

Comment: it did not work :(

Comment: The issue is resolved. You can check it from https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/1099

Answer (score 0):

I faced configuration file issue when changed it to .ts I created ‘.sequelizerc’ file and added config.ts filename to accept .ts file configuration.
The Error I faced-
ERROR: Error reading "config\config.ts". Error: TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"

This is working when we execute sequelize.sync() method. But while executing Sequelize migrations it doesn't work with .TS config file. When I changed it to .JS it started working.